# Remove all notifications from notification drawer

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

i want to remove all notifications from notification drawer not only my apps notification but all notification of other apps.
NotificationListenerService can do this but is there any other way to simply remove notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `cancel();` or `cancelAll();`

[Check out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int))

Comment: but this will remove notifications of my own app not all notifications of other apps also?

Comment: It's only for YOUR APP Notification. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661023/clear-another-apps-notification-via-the-accessibility-api (with accesibility android)

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me

```
NotificationManager.cancelAll() to remove all notification.
```

Comment: but this will remove notifications of my own app not all notifications of other apps also?